# CSS3 Columns: Firefox and Chrome different behavior

Tags: html, css

I have a website with an unordered list essentially like

```
      <ul class="subnav-links">
        <li class="">
          <a href="/de/t/new">New In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/de/t/sale">Sale</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/de/pages/best_looks">Looks</a>
        </li>
        .... more lis omitted
  </ul>
```

and css:

```
.subnav-links {
     -webkit-columns: 8 auto; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 8 auto; /* Firefox */
    columns: 8 auto;
}
```

On this [website](http://sv50.aarboard.ch/) Chrome shows the list items correctly in 8 columns but Firefox shows only 1 column.

Why is it so? And how can i fix it?

P.S. I wrapped also the subnav-ul inside a div.subnav-columns and styled the div with the columns property but Firefox keeps showing just one column.

Comment: there is no `subnav-colunms` in the site

Comment: yes, it was an attempt to style a div instead of the ul with the columns attribute but neither one is working in Firefox so i removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found it. I had a wrong nested `@-moz-document url-prefix()` in my stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Hav'nt you tried using this and applying it to CSS:

```
.subnav-links li { 
    display:inline-block; width:100% 
}
```

Comment: yes, with this the list-items are arranges horizontally row after row but i want the list-items to be vertically stacked in 8 columns.

Comment: means you want height of all list-items to be same. Which can make the columns stacked??

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your last comment correctly. What I was referring to in my comment a few minutes ago was the sort order of the list items. With the CSS3 columns attribute the sort order is to fill the list items in columns after columns (vertically stacked). With your approach in your first comment the list items get filled in rows after rows.

Comment: I understand you want items to be in vertical order but this is not possible in CSS3 Columns, if you want this you have to use floating or by display:inline-block; to the items...

Comment: it's possible and already implemented when you open the website with chrome/safari. there's a good article on a list apart: http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists